# Как узнать, куда ведет pipe:[номер] из /proc/self/fd/4?

Tags: linux, docker

Я решаю такую задачу: нужно отправлять вывод PHP-скрипта, работающего в фоновом режиме (background), внутри контейнера, в журнал докера. Запись в `/dev/stderr` и `/dev/stdout` для этого не подходит (они ведут в итоге в `/dev/null`).

Поэтому нужно среди `/proc/self/fd` найти дескриптор, запись в который выведется в журнале докера. Я выяснил, что `/proc/self/fd/4` для этого подходит и работает. Вот все дескрипторы:

```
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 0 -> /dev/null
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 1 -> pipe:[13054229]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 10 -> pipe:[13054229]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 11 -> pipe:[13054229]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 12 -> pipe:[13230601]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 2 -> pipe:[13054229]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 3 -> /var/www/artisan
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 4 -> pipe:[13054229]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 5 -> pipe:[13054230]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 6 -> /var/www/artisan
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 7 -> pipe:[13235313]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 8 -> pipe:[13235314]
root root 64 Feb 11 15:24 9 -> /var/www/artisan
```

Но эта цифра "4" может меняться из-за пересборки образа. Образ на основе Debian, сборкой управляю не я, набор средств ограничен, `lsof` отсутствует.

Поэтому я решил среди пайпов `find -L /proc/$pid/fd -type p` отфильтровать и найти подходящий - по названию процесса.

`stat /proc/$pid/fd/4`:

```
/proc/263/fd/pipe:[13054229]
  File: /proc/263/fd/4 -> pipe:[13054229]
  Size: 64          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   symbolic link
```

Вопрос 1. Как понять, куда ведет эта труба? Интересует название процесса. По нему я смогу вычислить, подходит она или нет.

Вопрос 2. Как эта труба правильно называется? "named pipe" не подходит, это другой механизм.

PS. Решить проблему проще не удастся.

Comment: а что-то банальное вроде `ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | grep -F 'pipe:[13054229]'` не показывает? и что значит «как эта труба правильно называется»?

Comment: О том, что означает это число https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608392

Comment: Обновил вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что я хочу сделать. `ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | grep -F 'pipe:[13054229]'` - есть какой-то более простой способ? lsof в системе нет, и поставить его нельзя.

Comment: Про задачу меня в первую очередь волнует, почему stderr и stdout ведут в `/dev/null`?

Comment: `Про задачу меня в первую очередь волнует, почему stderr и stdout ведут в /dev/null` - потому что https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71205/background-process-pipe-input и фактически оно так и есть

Comment: В этой ссылке не сказано ничего про stdout и stderr, так что всё равно непонятно, почему stderr и stdout у вас ведут в `/dev/null`

Comment: Я не знаю. Родитель PID 1 - это php. У него со stderr и stdout все в порядке. Далее выполняемый PHP скрипт запускает еще один скрипт, уже в фоне. У него эти выводы смотрял в /dev/null

Comment: Как именно он его запускает?

Comment: Запускается через [вендорское решение](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2454836de8f57b946efe01ed5afebb13d50ba321/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php#L292) - метод start. Я могу посмотреть точное значение, но в любом случае, код поменять невозможно.

Comment: @TotalPusher, принципиально другого способа найти, кто на втором конце трубы нет: можно только облагородить этот более аккуратным перебором… `lsof` делает тоже самое, если что… если это канал без имени, то он и называется, сюрприз, [*неименованный канал*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB) или *анонимная труба* ;). Это тот же объект, что получается при запуске в оболочке двух коменд через вертикальную черту (`foo | bar`) или при вызове `pipe(2)`…

Comment: ЗЫ: и я не совсем понимаю, что ты хочешь делать с этой трубой, когда её найдёшь…

Comment: `echo "foo" > /proc/$pid/fd/4` - так сообщения попадают в журнал. То же самое можно сделать на PHP, это проверено и работает. Проблема в постоянной смене "4". Может быть есть какие-то другие способы...

Comment: мм… думал, ты хочешь что-то из этой трубы попытаться прочитать — это было бы сильно сложнее… принципиально другого ничего быть не может: только перебор… лучшее на что можешь надеяться — найти какой-нить готовый скриптик или модуль, который предоставляет эту инфу в удобоваримом виде, дабы не велосипедить… но я сомневаюсь, что такой будет — задача несколько хачная…

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут надо настроить докер на получение syslog виртуальной машины в свой журнал.